# How to use "NOT IN"

Tags: mysql

I want to find all codes from **`promo_id = 1`** that does not exist in **`promo_id = 2`**

**Table name:** `promo_codes`

**Columns:** id, promo_id, code

```
SELECT code FROM promo_codes where promo_id=1 NOT IN

(SELECT code FROM promo_codes where promo_id=2);
```

I always get 0 row(s) returned, even though there are codes in **`promo_id = 1`** that does not exist in **`promo_id = 2`**

Comment: Already asked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519272/mysql-not-in-query

Comment: @Luuk that's a different issue. This one has a specific syntax misconstruction.

Answer (score 6):

You want to check in `code` is `NOT IN` that list of codes. Your syntax needs correction. Specifically, to use **`AND code NOT IN (...)`**:

```
SELECT code 
FROM promo_codes 
WHERE promo_id = 1 
  AND code NOT IN
      (SELECT code FROM promo_codes WHERE promo_id = 2) ;
```

---

If `code` is nullable, you should add one more check in the subquery to avoid `NULL` issues with `NOT IN`:

```
SELECT code 
FROM promo_codes 
WHERE promo_id = 1 
  AND code NOT IN
      (SELECT code
       FROM promo_codes
       WHERE promo_id = 2
         AND code IS NOT NULL) ;
```

Alternatively, you can use `NOT EXISTS` or `LEFT JOIN` / `IS NULL` check. They are often more efficient than `NOT IN (subquery)`, especially in older MySQL versions:

```
-- using NOT EXISTS
SELECT p1.code 
FROM promo_codes AS p1 
WHERE p1.promo_id = 1 
  AND NOT EXISTS
      (SELECT 1
       FROM promo_codes AS p2
       WHERE p2.promo_id = 2
         AND p2.code = p1.code) ;

-- using LEFT JOIN / IS NULL
SELECT p1.code 
FROM promo_codes AS p1 
     LEFT JOIN promo_codes AS p2
     ON  p2.promo_id = 2
     AND p2.code = p1.code
WHERE p1.promo_id = 1 
  AND p2.promo_id IS NULL ;
```

---

For efficiency, I suggest you add a composite index on `(promo_id, code)`, independent of which query you choose (and test them all to find out which runs faster in your case)

Answer (score 0):

If the not-in-list contains any nulls, then not-in always returns null.  So you get no rows.

```
SELECT code FROM promo_codes where promo_id=1 and code NOT IN
(SELECT code FROM promo_codes where promo_id=2 and code is not null);
```

You could also use "not exists", or "except".

Comment: That might be a problem, but only after they fix the syntax (see my answer ;)

Comment: You have two `WHERE`s!

Answer (score 0):

`NOT IN (<Select .. subquery>)` is generally inefficient in MySQL. You can also approach this problem using conditional aggregation based filtering using `Group By` and `Having` clauses:

```
Select code 
From promo_codes 
Where promo_id IN (1,2) 
Group By code 
Having Sum(promo_id = 1)
              And Not Sum(promo_id = 2)
```

Comment: Good but I would write it as: `Having Sum(promo_id = 1) > 0 
              And Sum(promo_id = 2) = 0`, so it is more clear. Or:  `Having COUNT(CASE WHEN promo_id = 1 THEN 1 END) > 0 AND COUNT(CASE WHEN promo_id = 2 THEN 1 END) = 0`

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want. The below query will run row by row and each code of promo_id 1 will be checked in (codes...) of promo_id 2 if theres a match then that row would be printed

```
    Select codes from table where 
      promo_id 
     =1 and codes NOT IN
     (SELECT CODES from table where 
      promo_code=2)
```